# notepad++: spacing between paragraphs

Tags: notepad++

I am looking for a way to increase the spacing between paragraphs in *notepad++*. With "spacing between paragraphs" I am referring to the spacing only after a newline character, not the spacing between wrapped parts of a line.
I have found solutions only for the latter related problem, which I was not looking for.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this kind of spacing between paragraphs?

Comment: Notepad++ is a plain text editor. It has no concepts of paragraphs

Comment: I agree. Perhaps I need to clarify: I am not looking for a way to set the spacing for individual paragraphs as it is possible in rich word processing software, but for a global option, changing the way how all text is presented to the user.

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75520684/edit) and add sample text **and** expected result. As weel as what you have tried.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.